# joint density of two random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be random variables with density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the joint density function $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

If they are not independent, how can we find the joint density function(if it exists)?

Comment: Without additional information - we can't, different joint distributions can have the same component wise densities.

Comment: You might be interested to research about this though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory).

Answer (score 0):

We can't. Say $X$ and $Y$ are both uniform on $[0,1]$. Then if they are independent, $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the unit square. If, on the other hand, $X=Y$, then $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. One can certainly find more exotic joint distributions too with the same component-wise distributions.